# Dynamic JLable Text

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jframe, jpanel

I'm a super Java noob and need some help.  I am trying to write a code that shows the word "on" on the JPanel for 5 (or however long I pass into y variable) seconds then changes the word to "off" on the same JPanel.  Think of a stoplight that shows green for a period of time then goes to red.  The code I have written below opens up two separate JFrames to display the different words.  Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class practice extends JFrame implements Runnable {

int  x;
int y;
JLabel show = new JLabel("on");

JLabel show2 = new JLabel("off");
boolean yes;


public practice(boolean on, int x){
    x=y;
    yes = on;
    setTitle("Stoplight");
    setSize(500, 500);
    setResizable(true);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


}



public void test(){
    try {

        Thread.sleep(y);

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (yes == true){
        add(show2);
    }else if (yes == false)
         add(show);

}

public void run() {
    test();
}

public static void main (String[] args){

    Thread t1 = new Thread(new practice(true, 50000));
    Thread t2 = new Thread(new practice(false, 0));
    t1.start();
    t2.start();

}



    }
```

Comment: Use [`javax.swing.Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for this.

Answer (score 1):

You need remove the label 'on' of panel before add the label 'off' with the method remove(jcomponent)

Comment: Better to simply change the text

Answer (score 1):

As has already been hinted, you should use a [`javax.swing.Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html), which will allow you to schedule a callback after a specified period of time.

Unless you have a particular need, it's simpler to change the text of the label to have to remove the old label and add a new one (IMHO)

For example...

[image: Dynamic Label]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class DynamicLabel {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new DynamicLabel();
    }

    public DynamicLabel() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane(5000));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JLabel label;

        public TestPane(int delay) {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            setBorder(new EmptyBorder(8, 8, 8, 8));
            label = new JLabel("On");
            add(label);

            Timer timer = new Timer(delay, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    label.setText("Off");
                }
            });
            timer.setRepeats(false);
            timer.start();
        }

    }

}
```